# In CoffeeScript how would I call a class method from another class such that both classes instances are stored in a third class?

Tags: class, coffeescript

In CoffeeScript how would I call a class method from another class such that both classes instances are stored in a third class?

**Demonstration:**

```
class A

  constructor: () ->

    @b = new B
    @c = new C
```

---

```
class B

  methodB: () ->
```

---

```
class C

  methodC: () ->
    ### How would I call instance b's methodB from here? ###
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to do this is to have a reference to an instance of the `A` class. For example, if I understand what you're trying to do correctly:

```
class A
  constructor: () ->
    @b = new B
    @c = new C(this)

class B
  methodB: () ->

class C
  constructor (@parent) ->
  methodC: () ->
    @parent.b.methodB()
```

The instance of `C` has no idea that the instance of `A` has a reference to it -- there's no built-in concept of `c` "belonging" to the `a` that constructed it (it wouldn't make sense if there was); you have to make that explicit.

Comment: Thank You. Would it also be acceptable to develop the classes as singletons as described here: http://coffeescriptcookbook.com/chapters/design_patterns/singleton then you could acces the class method from the root.

Comment: @JamieFearon JavaScript (and by extension CoffeeScript) is a dynamic enough language that you don't need to implement the singleton pattern in the same way that you do for a statically typed language like Java. If you want one and only one `A`, you can just make it an object. You don't have to jump through hoops like that.

Comment: Ian, I have tred your answer and it doesn't work, I get the error 'Cannot read property 'addBTS' of undefined ' when @parent.b.methodB() is called

Comment: There is no `addBTS` in the code I posted. That sounds like a separate issue.

Comment: Sorry addBTS is equivalent to b in the question, could you possibly get your code to work in a JSFiddle?

Comment: @JamieFearon There's a typo in my answer (a missing colon after `C`'s constructor). The fact that you got that far in execution implies to me that you spotted it already, so I'm not sure what the error you're referring to is from. Here's the compiled JS code, with added alerts to signify that the methods are being called: http://jsfiddle.net/ZpNwv/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25026/discussion-between-jamie-fearon-and-ian-henry)

Answer (score 0):

You would need a reference to an instance of the other class, e.g.

```
class A

  constructor: () ->
    @b = new B
    @c = new C

    @c.setB(@b)
    @c.methodC() # Also calls B.methodB()

class B

  methodB: () ->


class C

  methodC: () ->
    @b.methodB()

  setB: (@b) ->
```